# ImportError: No module named modules.logic

Tags: python, import

I get this whenever I start my program.
It did work till an hour ago, I must somehow have deleted something important
I have already found out here that it might have to do with `__init__.py` - However, I have one of those in every module.

Is there any other reason this could occur for?

If I checkout anything, I get this:

```
M   main.py
D   modules/__init__.py
M   modules/logic/game.py
```

However, I am not able to find out what this means (have you ever tried to google a single letter, like M, oder D?)

Comment: *Loads* of reasons. Altered `sys.path`, local file named `modules.py` in your current directory, deleted modules, etc. Can you provide more details at all?

Comment: What details do you need?

Comment: The question is equivalent to calling your doctor and saying: "Doctor, I sneezed and now it hurts. Can you fix me over the phone?" You will have to provide some details.

Comment: A stack trace might help. Source code that is the root of this error. Then we could ask focused questions and get you an answer.

Comment: The actual module name, does `import modules` work, what does `modules.__file__` give in that case. Did you check if your `sys.path` is sane. Details!

Comment: The problem is I understand none of what you are saying, and not because of language. I do not know how to check a sys.path, I am not even sure if I know WHAT that is. Also, there is no stacktrace whatsoever, all I get is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrea/game-engineering/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from modules.logic import game
ImportError: No module named modules.logic
#

Comment: When you say "check out anything"... is that a call to `svn status`? (If so, it indicates that `__init__.py` has been deleted)

Comment: OP, try writing a small Python script, maybe just a few lines, that has the same problem. Paste that script into your question. Paste all the output of that script also into the question. Try to remember what you did in the last hour that could have caused your program to stop working. Type whatever you remember into the question. This will get a  better discussion started. More questions will surely follow but at this time there is not much to go on. P.S. Also see [this](http://goo.gl/KQUNZ).

Comment: No I am using git. It means using git checkout, on any branch. Ahm...I would do what you wish, only, If I do not know why the problem occured in the first place, how on earth should I know how to reproduce it?

Comment: Just in case I might have deleted some __init__.py, how do I get it back? And yes, I might have, as I have been adding a new module and deleting that repeatedly, so I might accidentally have deleted sth., but If so, I would not know what and how to get it back.

Comment: I fixed it! You were all right, it was a deleted init, and there was an option in my IDE to get it back which I was not aware of! Thanks everyone and sorry to have bothered you!

Comment: @newnewbie Congratulations for finding a fix for the problem. Sorry for all the pesky questions but please try to see it from the readers' perspective. The more details you provide at the very beginning the faster you are likely to get an answer. I am sure I have made the same mistake of typing a question in a hurry because I was panicking. But it helps tremendously to take a deep breath and read your question a couple of times before posting it. Good luck in the future. :)

Comment: Thank you. See, I usually just do not know which question is needed. Also, it seems to be a deeper Problem because now, I have the same problem with another module. This module is MILES away from what I was just working on. It is not funny if all the time modules keep disappearing without any hint why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That output looks like you are using either svn or git. The letter **D** means the file were deleted, **M** means modified. The bad news is the file `__init__.py` was deleted. The good news is you can still recover them. Just google *svn recover deleted file*.

More importantly, you probably need to talk to the person who deleted it (use `svn log`) and learn the rationale behind it.

#### Update

It seems you are using git, but the advice is the same, the git command syntax in this context should be the same, or close to the svn syntax.

Comment: For svn: `svn revert FILENAME`, for git: take a look at `git checkout`